# Is Google Cloud Storage object composition strongly consistent?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, consistency

Google Cloud Storage supports S3-compatible multipart uploads and [mentions](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/post-object-complete) that "[it] can take several minutes to process a request to complete a multipart upload". Does the same apply to [the compose operation of the JSON API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/compose)? Is it guaranteed that after composing an object with the JSON API, it will become immediately available for reading and listing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once a `Compose` operation completes the resulting object is immediately readable and list-able.